# How to open pdf file in the app using Flutter

Tags: flutter

I am using `flutter_pdfview` which is version ^1.0.0+10 to open a PDF file in flutter apps. When my app is in debug mode, there is no error. After I build the app the PDF file cannot open in apps. My app will crash and close suddenly. I have open the permission in AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

How can solve this error?

Comment: please post the exception.

Comment: @JohnJoe Thank you for your reply, I cannot see the exception. It is because after I flutter build apk, then install the app it not in debug mode already.

Comment: and in debug mode it working and did not have any error

Answer (score 1):

First you need to create a `proguard-rules.pro` file at `/android/app/` inside there write like this:

```
#Flutter Wrapper
-keep class com.shockwave.**
```

Then at `/android/app/build.gradle` add this:

```
buildTypes {
        release {

            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            **minifyEnabled true
            useProguard true

            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'**
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I have this problem only on android but when the app is on production. To fix this I add the permission handler plugin and change the path. Also and very important was add the extension ".pdf" to file after download but before read.

```
final filename = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
var request = await HttpClient().getUrl(Uri.parse(url));
var response = await request.close();
var bytes = await consolidateHttpClientResponseBytes(response);
String dir = (await getExternalStorageDirectory()).path;
File file = new File('$dir/$filename.pdf');
await file.writeAsBytes(bytes);      
pathPDF = file.path;
return file;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are running debug on an emulator and then release on a real device, this might be your problem:

> PdfViewPage(path: '/storage/emulated/0/Download/$pdfName')));

Even if it isn't causing the crash it is a bad idea to hardcode download path like you've done. Different devices can have downloads in different locations. You can use [downloads_path_provider](https://pub.dev/packages/downloads_path_provider) to find where downloads is located.

Also, beside declaring the permissions needed in the Manifest you should also ask user for permission and handle the situation if the user doesn't give permission. For that task I suggest using [permission_handler](https://pub.dev/packages/permission_handler).

Comment: thank you for your reply, I have use this package to do permission also but it still have error